# How to call and pass parameters to a fragment from a button click event on the listview group

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list view with a button and a textview in the group header.
I uses an adapter that implements the view holder.

I want to include a click event on the button such that I get the textview text that is in the group header and I want to pass the string to another fragment.

I also want to show the other fragment.

I am stuck as I can`t figure out,

1. How to read the textview value from the expandable listview in the fragment on the button click
   and
2. How to pass the value of Title to another fragment.

Do I need to use

```
 GViewHolder.myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {    
        }
```

or

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
});
```

Please note that I can`t see public void onItemClick being hit when the button is clicked!

---

I have implemented an adapter as follows:
Part of the code is

```
   public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    class GViewHolder {
     public TextView Title;
     public Button myButton;
    }
   GViewHolder.myButton.setFocusable(false);
   GViewHolder.myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


 // How to implement this in the fragment ???
    }
   });
 }
```

---

Part of the fragment that implements the Adapter as follows:

```
   private ListView eList = null;
   InterFragmentNavigator interFragmentNavigator;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_list, container, false);
   eList = (ListViewAdapter) view.findViewById(R.id.eView);
   ListViewAdapter listDataAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), groupes);
   eList.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);

   eList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

// Here, I want to read the textview value of Title next to button

 TextView textViewItem = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Title));
 String Title = textViewItem.getText().toString();
**//Here, I want to call another fragment and pass Title as parameter.**                

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you are creating new fragment from the click then add something like.

```
Fragment detailFragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("TITLE", "your title");
detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then do the transection here. Then in the detailFragment you can do

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String title = bundle.getString("TITLE") ;
```

Comment: Just to mention it, he should use childFragmentManager to add the new fragment

Comment: Thanks, do I need to implement GViewHolder.myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

   }
   });

Comment: Since you have onItemClick in your fragment and assuming you want to call new fragment by clicking on a list item then you don't need the onClickListener again. Unless your list item has a button and you want a different handling of the button then yes you need the onClickListener. And if you have time do look into a nice library called butterknife. It's really cool.?